# The right way to move to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a project in Objective C that used slidemenu from [this](https://github.com/iDevelopper/PBRevealViewController). From each page on its menu, it has 3 button in bottom 
[image: Slidemenu]

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`'s left menu table, I can "move" to 1,2, and 3 view controller by using

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyStoryboardViewController"]];
[self.revealViewController pushMainViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

On 1, 2, and 3 View Controller, I initialize hamburger menu on navigation item with this

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
UIImage *imgBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"];
[barButton setImage:imgBtn];

barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
barButton.action = @selector(revealLeftView);

self.revealViewController.toggleAnimationType = PBRevealToggleAnimationTypePushSideView;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

And each view controller has custom UIView that consist of 3 button. It is like bottom tab bar on Spotify for iOS. It will navigate to A, B, and C view controller that has slidemenu button also.
[image: Bottom button]

Right now, I can navigate to A, B, and C by creating delegate on its custom view
that require instance of destination UIViewController as parameter so I can present that view controller using

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But as the result, A, B, and C view controller can't initialize its slidemenu using code like on 1, 2, and 3 view controller. It hamburger menu is created, but it can't show slidemenu as it should be.

So where I did wrong here? I think my fault is on how to present A, B, and C view controller that use `presentViewController`. Or another one? Any sugestion would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Instead of:

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Use:

```
[self.revealViewController setMainViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

In this case the vc controller presented will keep a revealViewController property as it is presented with it.

As its developer said [here](https://github.com/iDevelopper/PBRevealViewController/issues/21#issuecomment-274522657)

Thank you so much!